# Automating acquisition of speed limit data from a source such as google maps API, etc

Tags: google-maps-api-3, data-collection

So, I developed a math model for optimizing biking routes based on user preference, and I am trying to develop an application where the solution is solved using Dijkstra's algorithms (and of course graphs). Part of the weighting of the edges is based on the speed limit of a road so my question is:

Is there a good open-source library, such as Google Maps API or something similar, where I could automate the collection of this data? It would be impossible to do this for the graph in question by hand (the city of Seattle, WA), but I don't know where I can automate (or write a program to semi-automate), the collection of speed limit data, or even acquire it in the first place. I basically need a source of speed limit information, and google maps seems the most promising, but I cannot find anything.

Thanks,

tylerthemiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed that kind of data a few years back, but with no luck. Google doesn`t give that data, Navteq and Teleatlas with the same issue. The best temporary solution ( until you will find an accurate  way to do that ) is to get the standard speed limit for all the road types in your country/city/etc, and match it againnst the current road type . This will provide you a good start in your application and in most of the cases the speed limit is the one specified by law.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Did you find a good way of automating the I.D.ing of road types though?? I am working with a big area and this would be hard to do by hand.

Comment: This thread might help you: http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/78469161c2072e85?pli=1